# appcelerator titanium create ScrollView with pagination control

Tags: titanium, scrollview, appcelerator

I need create a ScrollableView with two simultaneous views.
looking at the image is better understood

[desired prototype](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgDWW.png)

I tried to synchronize 2 ScrollableView, to make a continuous ScrollableView false and get the effect. But I could not synchronize the movements of the ScrollableView

[2 ScrollableView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQdQ9.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the "continuous slide" (quickly slide through all views) then I would use the ScrollView and implement the stop part in the scrollend event. Check if a multiple of your view width is half the width in or not and then move to the beginning or end of the view. Its a bit hard to describe :)

If you just need it for iOS you can use clipView:

http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.ScrollableView-property-clipViews

to show the previous/next view.

Comment: Yes, It´s perfect for me, now in Android ¿Don't have solution?